# power apps, Search box with numbers and string

Tags: powerapps

I am trying to search in a table by id (integer) and name (string), but power apps says that the Search function has incorrect parameters because Search function accept only text:

```
Search('myTble';TextInput.Text;"name";"id")
```

I tried this one but the id field is not recognized even by putting the table name on top:

```
Search('myTable';TextInput.Text;"name";Text("id"))
```

Anyone any idea?
Thanks very much!

Comment: Is it anything to do with the mixed quotes you're using?  One set is single quote, the other double quotes.

Comment: No HSS, it's not a problem with mixed quotes

Answer (score 0):

Find out how to achieve it:

```
Search(
    AddColumns('myTable';"id_text";Text(id)) 
    ;Text(TextInput.Text);"name";"id_text"
    )
```

Add a column to your table converting the id in text, and then search on that new column.
Easy easy! :)